# Launching the Mail.app from my application

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my application, i need to launch the `Mail.app` of Apple. The screen i need to show to the user is

[image]

so that he can select whichever option he wants.

Using the `MFMailComposeViewController` shows the mail composition interface

[image]

Is is possible to launch the `Mail.app` programmatically, or is it forbidden by Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:adress@example.com"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```

Comment: +1 as yes this should work, but I would make one minor addition. I would wrap the `openURL:` line in an `if statement` like `if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:myURL]) {` only a minor change but it will avoid any possible issues if it can't be opened even though I believe every iDevice does have the mail app.